# Modifying a QVector of QVectors passed as a pointer

Tags: qt, qvector

I have a variable in the argument of a function that is defined like this:

```
QVector< QVector<qreal> > *var;
```

In a certain point of the code I want to do this:

```
*var[i][j] = some_value.
```

However this does not compile because

> error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*(var + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)row) * 8ul)))->QVector::operator[] with T = QVector’

How do I properly reference the value so that it is modified? (The idea is that the parameter passed in the function is really modified.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `*var` in parentheses:

```
(*var)[i][j] = some_value;
```

Though why are you using a pointer to a `QVector`? Since `QVector` is part of Qt's generic containers family, it uses implicit sharing. This means that if you pass-by-value instead, you'll only perform a shallow copy, which is to say that you'll effectively only be passing the thin book-keeping part of the data structure - a pointer to a larger block of data which exists elsewhere.

Comment: I did not know that. what I wanted to avoid is copying the entire structure and the having to copy the entire structure again when returning it. If I pass by value then the entire copy is not done? Thank you!

Comment: Nope, passing by value only copies `QVector`'s 'bookkeeping' data (five `int`s and one `long` on Windows, regardless of the content type of the `QVector` or how many items it contains). See the [Qt docs on Implicit Sharing](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/implicit-sharing.html) for more information :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll change it as y prefer the non pointer approach